# Calculating indexes in a filtered array

Tags: arrays

Suppose I have an array `A = {a,b,c,d,e,f,g}` and a set of (zero-based) indexes `I={1,3,5}`  in `A`. Now suppose that I actually don't have `A`, but only the array which is the result of removing the indexes specified in `I` from `A`, i.e. `B = {a,c,e,g}` (I also have `I` itself).

Given an index in `B`, can I analytically calculate the corresponding index in `A`? For example, for the index 3 in `B` the answer should be 6.

It's easy to think of a `O(|A|)` solution, but it's unacceptable as `A` can get pretty big. A `O(|I|)` solution should be fine. Also note that `I` may periodically change (more indexes removed).

Comment: you mean like A.indexOf( B.get(3))

Comment: @gnanz - no, the items are just an example; there is no guarantee for uniqueness. Besides, I don't have access to `A` itself.

Comment: @brokenfoot, I'm working with Java but I'll be happy with an answer in any comprehensible language.

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean by "I also have I itself". Can you give an example of your actual input for the above example?

Comment: @AssafLavie, it means I know the set of removed indices. In the above example my input is `B = {a,c,e,g}`, `I={1,3,5}` and `|A|=7` (and some index in B which should be converted to the corresponding index in A).

Comment: I'm afraid I really don't follow. You use B once as an array and once as an index...? Is this just an unfortunate choice of variable names?

Comment: No, `B` is always an array. I didn't name the given index in `B`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use an array that for each of the elements in `B` would have the number of elements before that index that were removed `{0,1,2,3}` then one would take the index into `B` and look up in that array and add that value to the index into `B` to get the index into `A`. This would take additional space equal to the size of `B` but would be `O(1)`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it's unlikely to be feasible in my case. Since `A` gets pretty big but `I` remains rather small, `B` gets pretty big as well.

Comment: @YodanTauber The array can be compressed easily as intervals and a binary search used. As in those intervals the offset to add is the same. Yielding a `O(log N)` lookup cost.

Answer (score 0):

"I" splits original array into some slices. We can get B concatenating these slice. With `I={1,3,5}` we get slices `{0, 0}, {2,2}, {4,4}, {6,lastA}` We can create an ordered map where the keys are indices in B and the values are slices.

```
{ 0: {0,0}, 1: {2, 2}, 2: {4, 4}, 3: {6,lastA} }
```

Actually, we don't need to keep upper bound of each slice

```
{ 0: 0, 1: 2, 2: 4, 3: 6 }
```

In C++ code make look like this:

```
std::function<size_t (size_t)> getIndexConverter(size_t sizeOfA, std::vector<size_t> I)
{
    std::map<size_t, size_t> abIndices;
    size_t sliceStart = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0, imax = I.size(); i < imax; ++i) {
        if (sliceStart < I[i])
            abIndices.emplace(sliceStart - i, sliceStart);
        sliceStart = I[i] + 1;
    }
    if (sliceStart < sizeOfA)
        abIndices.emplace(sliceStart - I.size(), sliceStart);
    return [abIndices](size_t bIndex) -> size_t {
        auto slice = abIndices.lower_bound(bIndex);
        assert(slice != abIndices.end()); // it is impossible because of algorithm we use to construct abIndices
        return bIndex - slice->first + slice->second;
    };
}
```

[full example on Ideone](http://ideone.com/734RTq)

This method requires additional memory equal to number of slices and executes with logarithmic time.

Comment: Thanks! However, are you sure about `lower_bound`? For example, in the case of an empty `I`, the only slice is `{0,0}`, and then the `lower_bound` for any index greater than 0 will be the end of the map (unless I'm totally misinterpreting the documentation of `lower_bound` and `upper_bound`, which do not seem like opposites at all).

Comment: lower_bound returns an iterator pointing to the first key in the map that is not less than (i.e. greater or equal to) value. So if map contains only one key "0" then lower_bound returns iterator to "0". This should always work.

Comment: There is a one case when lower_bound will not work. `sizeOfA == 0`

Comment: if the map only contains "0", then lower_bound(1) cannot return "0" because it is strictly less than 1:
http://ideone.com/B7Usrn

Comment: You are right. In this case we should only return bIndex as a result of conversion.